# FileNotFoundException from WCF service

Tags: c#, io, filenotfoundexception

I have a WCF service which basically reads some records from xml and provides handy functions to client which return data as objects.Here is my code in a service function

```
        //read schema
        XmlSchemaSet schema = new XmlSchemaSet();
        schema.Add("", XmlReader.Create(new StreamReader("RecordsSchema.xsd")));

        //read Xml file
        string inputUrl = "myRecords.xml";
        var xDoc = XDocument.Load(inputUrl);

        //validate file is as per schema
        xDoc.Validate(schema, new ValidationEventHandler(ValidateSchema));
```

When I consume this function from client ,I get System.IO.FileNotFound exception.The schema files is in output directory of my wcf application.How can I make them accessible for client calls?

Comment: Client and service binaries are located in same directory ? Where does the compiler fails exactly ? on what line ? XDocument.Load(inputUrl); ?

Comment: Provide a full path or make sure the working directory is set to your "output path". Also I assume this is hosted in IIS?

Comment: This is hosted on IIS ,TCP binding and my xml and schema are under App_Data folder of service project.

Comment: If you cannot debug the service, If i were you, i would log the current directory where the DLL is running AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, and then check if there is xml/scheme files there, and if you have privilege to run/save files on that location.

Comment: @TRS again: provide a full path or make sure the working directory is set to the App_Data folder. Show what you have tried, show you understand the error, find out where it is trying to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all,

I resolved my problem with this

```
private readonly string mSchemaPath = Path.Combine(HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath, "App_Data", "RecordSchema.xsd");
private readonly string mXmlPath = Path.Combine(HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath, "App_Data", "Records.xml");
```